# How to I get access to data from other functions in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What are some of the best practices to get access to data from other functions to my React Component?

I have a very simple component as :

```
/* eslint-disable */
import React from 'react'
import { test } from './FunctionTest'

function Component() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is from Component</h1>
      <p>{test()}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Component
```

I am importing a function called `test` from a file called `FunctionTest`. The file is as follows :

```
export function test() {
  let a = 2
  return a
}
```

My goal is to access the data `a` from which is returning from `FunctionTest` file, to my `component.js` file. Clearly, by doing  `<p>{test()}</p>` is totally not the right way.

I would like to ask what are best practices to do this, and how does it relate to `props` as `FunctionTest`  is simply a JS function and not a `React Component`

I have seen other answers over here, but they are much more complicated, so in case of closing this question, please make sure I am getting pointed to the right resources.

Any help would be great.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I don't see why you think what you're doing is wrong. You can either call the function inside the return statement of the Component (like you are doing) or call it inside the Component function body. Either way is fine.

Comment: Is this the best practice to call the function inside the return?

Comment: If you only want to render the result of the function, then yes that's the best practice. If you wanted to do some other calculation first, it might be better to call the function before the return statement and do the calculation there. Other than that, it's all really down to opinion, but what you're doing is totally fine. As a developer who reviews other peoples' React code regularly at my workplace, I would have no issue with the code you've written above.

Comment: I will point out however, that if the function being called is doing something like fetching data, or other asynchronous operations that return a promise, obviously you would have to call that in a useEffect and set state within the component once the result was returned, as you can't render a promise object.

Comment: For this kind of requirement you can simply use interface instead of function